# What is limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty}((\frac{a^x+b^x}{2})^{1/x})$?

Tags: limits, infinity

How I can calculate limite of this equation?! It can be solved using a famous theorem but I forgot it, may someone help me to calculate and prove it or even remind me the theorem?

$$
\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{\frac1x}
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.MV, I want the limits in both situation, when $x\to -\infty$ and  $x\to +\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $a\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} &=\,a\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}
\end{align}$$

If $a=b$, then the limit is obviously equal to $a$.

Now, we assume without loss of generality that $a>b$.  Then, it is easy to see that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} &=\,a\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}\\\\
&=a\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp\left(\log \left(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} \right)\\\\
&=a \exp\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac1x \,\log \left(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2}\right) \right)\\\\
&=a \exp\left(\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac1x\right) \times \lim_{x \to \infty} \log \left(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2}\right) \right)\\\\
&=a \exp\left(0 \times \log \left(\frac12\right) \right)\\\\
&=a
\end{align}$$

Of course, one might have observed that inasmuch as (1) $b/a<1$, and (2) $y^{1/x} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ for $0<y<1$, then (3) $(b/a)^{x}$ approaches zero as $x \to \infty$ and thus (4) $(\frac{1+(b/a)^x}{2})^{1/x} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.

---

Note that if the limit were $x \to -\infty$, then we proceed analogously.

We assume that $a\ge 0$ and $b\ge 0$ and write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} &=\,b\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\frac{1+(a/b)^x}{2}\right)^{1/x}
\end{align}$$

If $a=b$, then the limit is obviously equal to $b$.

Now, we assume without loss of generality that $a>b$.  Then, it is easy to see that as $x \to -\infty$, the term $(a/b)^x$ goes to zero and $(1/2)^{1/x} \to 1$.  Thus,

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} =b$$

Comment: I don't understand why this answer received a down vote.

Comment: Thank you Dr., how about $x\to-\infty$?

Comment: Sure.  My pleasure.  For $x \to -\infty$, one factors out $\min(a,b)$ and proceeds identically.  So, the answer is $\min(a,b)$.

Comment: @S0H31L I added the case for $x \to -\infty$ as requested.  Let me know if this helps.  I just want to give you the best answer possible.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**: We have
$$\dfrac{\max(a^x,b^x)}2 \leq \dfrac{a^x+b^x}2 \leq \max(a^x,b^x)$$
Hence,
$$\dfrac{\max(a,b)}{2^{1/x}} \leq \left(\dfrac{a^x+b^x}2\right)^{1/x} \leq \max(a,b)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot user17762, what theorem you used here?!

Comment: @S0H31L No, theorem. the only thing used here is $a^x \leq \max(a^x,b^x)$ and $b^x \leq \max(a^x,b^x)$. Further, $\max(a^x,b^x) \leq a^x+b^x$.

Comment: Ok, Thank you @user17762 again.

Comment: Another question about the answer, your answer works when $x\to +\infty$ and  $x\to -\infty$ or only it is the case when  $x\to +\infty$?! how about $x\to -\infty$ ?!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\;a\ge b>0\;$ , then

$$L:=(a^x+b^x)^{1/x}=b\left(1+\left(\frac ab\right)^x\right)^{1/x}$$

Now observe that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\left(\frac ab\right)^x\right)}x\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac ab\right)^x\log\frac ab}{1+\left(\frac ab\right)^x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\log\frac ab$$

so that

$$\left(1+\left(\frac ab\right)^x\right)^{1/x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}e^
{\log\frac ab}=\frac ab\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}L=b\frac ab=a $$

Of course, $\;2^{1/x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1\;$

Comment: Thank you @Timbuc, your answer works when $x\to +\infty$ and  $x\to -\infty$ or only it is the case when  $x\to +\infty$?! how about $x\to -\infty$ ?!

Comment: When $\;x\to -\infty\;$ the limit below "Observe that..." , both numerator and denominator converge to zero so this limit is  zero and thus the whole thing's limit is $\;b\cdot e^0=b\;$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(a^x+b^x)^{1/x}}{2^{1/x}}$$

now we have two cases as follows
 if $a\geq b$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{(a^x(1+(b/a)^x)^{1/x}}{2^{1/x}})=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a(1+(b/a)^{x})^{1/x}}{2^{1/x}}=a$$

and when b>a the limit becomes $b$

Comment: Thank you @Hard, your answer works when $x\to +\infty$ and  $x\to -\infty$ or only it is the case when  $x\to +\infty$?! how about $x\to -\infty$ ?!